# Sinclair Spectrum TAP file dumper

Tags: c++, file, c++17, serialization, file-structure

The other day, I had occasion to want to look into an ancient piece of Z80 software written for a [Sinclair Spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum) computer.  Software for this machine was typically saved to audio tape, and today people use the [TAP format](https://faqwiki.zxnet.co.uk/wiki/TAP_format) to store and exchange Spectrum software.  The format is a very literal translation of the original tape format and consists of a sequence of blocks (here rendered as `TAPBlock` class).  Typical format is that there is a header (`TAPHeader` in this code) followed by a code block.  An example is the [Wizard's Lair](https://worldofspectrum.org/archive/software/games/wizards-lair-yodasoft#game_files) game from 1984.

### The purpose

The purpose of this software is to simply read the file and dump the contents into somewhat structured, human readable form.  I was mostly interested in looking at strings of hex bytes (that's what passes for "human readable" in my house!) so that's the format I used here.  Everything works as intended.  Partial sample output is shown below for the game file mentioned above.

```
{ len = 19, flag = 0, {
        00 77 6c 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 c7 3e 02 00 c7 
        3e 
}, cksum = 25, calcsum = 25 }
{ type = 0, filename = "wl        ", data_len = 16071, param1 = 2, param2 = 16071 }
{ len = 16073, flag = 255, {
        00 01 0a 00 ec 31 30 0e 00 00 0a 00 00 0d 00 02 
        0d 00 fd 34 39 39 39 39 0e 00 00 4f c3 00 0d 00 
        ...
        33 36 37 36 0e 00 00 7c 5c 00 2c 31 39 39 0e 00 
        00 c7 00 00 3a fe 0d 
}, cksum = 122, calcsum = 122 }
{ len = 19, flag = 0, {
        03 77 6c 7a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 38 07 50 c3 00 
        80 
}, cksum = 110, calcsum = 110 }
{ type = 3, filename = "wlz       ", data_len = 1848, param1 = 50000, param2 = 32768 }
{ len = 1850, flag = 255, {
        00 00 00 00 18 3c 7e 7e 7e 5a 7e 3c 24 3c 3c 18 
        00 03 07 01 06 06 0f 07 e7 f7 ff ff ff 9f 0f 88 
        ...
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
}, cksum = 209, calcsum = 209 }
{ len = 19, flag = 0, {
        03 77 6c 62 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 6e 02 60 ea c3 
        80 
}, cksum = 255, calcsum = 255 }
{ type = 3, filename = "wlb       ", data_len = 622, param1 = 60000, param2 = 32963 }
{ len = 624, flag = 255, {
        c0 38 00 3d 0e 72 0e 71 1c 43 1c 48 2f c0 43 1c 
        43 0e c0 72 0e 72 08 79 08 77 21 71 21 71 1c c0 
        ...
        bf 94 c0 bf 8f b8 8d b0 8f a9 8e c0 ad 8a bf 89 
        ff 50 35 0a 5a 38 64 5a a8 7a 5a c8 0c ff 
}, cksum = 170, calcsum = 170 }
{ len = 19, flag = 0, {
        03 77 6c 62 62 20 20 20 20 20 20 77 01 00 fa 80 
        80 
}, cksum = 148, calcsum = 148 }
{ type = 3, filename = "wlbb      ", data_len = 375, param1 = 64000, param2 = 32896 }
{ len = 377, flag = 255, {
        d9 e1 d9 c9 d9 e5 d9 21 34 eb 7e fe ff 28 f1 fe 
        c0 20 0b 23 7e 32 c9 fa 23 7e 32 ca fa 23 7e 32 
        ...
        44 42 00 00 3c 40 3c 02 42 3c 00 00 fe 10 10 10 
        10 10 2a b2 5c ed 5b 
}, cksum = 176, calcsum = 176 }
```

### My questions

I didn't much like the way I have created the `TAPHeader` constructor.  I considered doing something even more ugly with `static_cast<TAPHeader>(data.data())` but the less said about that the better.  Is there a better way to do this?  Any other comments on ways to improve the code are also welcome.  I'm using C++17 for this, but would not be averse to C++20 if that provides some compelling feature that would be useful here.

### tapdump.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>

struct TAPHeader {
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t filename[11];  // actually 10 bytes, but we add NUL terminator
    uint16_t data_len;
    uint16_t param1;
    uint16_t param2;

    explicit TAPHeader(const std::vector<uint8_t> v) {
        auto it = v.begin();
        type = *it++;
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            filename[i] = *it++;
        }
        filename[10] = '\0';  // terminate filename string
        data_len = *it++;
        data_len |= *it++ << 8;
        param1 = *it++;
        param1 |= *it++ << 8;
        param2 = *it++;
        param2 |= *it++ << 8;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const TAPHeader& hdr) {
        return out 
            << "{ type = " << (unsigned)hdr.type
            << ", filename = \"" << hdr.filename
            << "\", data_len = " << hdr.data_len
            << ", param1 = " << hdr.param1
            << ", param2 = " << hdr.param2
            << " }";
    }
};

class TAPBlock {
    uint16_t len;   // little-endian
    uint8_t flag;  // 0 = header, 0xff = body        
    uint8_t cksum; // simple xor of data, excluding len
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
public:
    uint8_t calcsum() const {
        return std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), flag, std::bit_xor<uint8_t>());
    }
    bool is_ok() const { return calcsum() == cksum; }

    std::optional<TAPHeader> get_header() const {
        if (flag == 0 && data.size() >= 17) {
            return TAPHeader{data};
        }
        return {};
    }


    bool read(std::istream& in) {
        uint8_t lo, hi;
        lo = in.get();
        hi = in.get();
        len = (hi << 8) | lo;
        flag = in.get();
        data.clear();
        data.reserve(len-2);
        for (auto count{len-2}; count; --count) {
            data.push_back(in.get());
        }
        cksum = in.get();
        return in.good();
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const TAPBlock blk) {
        out << "{ len = " << std::dec << blk.len << ", flag = " << (unsigned)blk.flag << ", {";
        if (1 || blk.flag) {
            int remaining{0};
            for (auto n : blk.data) {
                if (remaining == 0) {
                    remaining = 16;
                    out << "\n\t";
                }
                --remaining;
                out << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << (unsigned)n << ' ';
            }
            out << "\n}, ";
        } else {

        }
        return out << "cksum = " << std::dec << (unsigned)blk.cksum
            << ", calcsum = " << std::dec << (unsigned)blk.calcsum() << " }";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: dumptap tapfilename\n";
        return 1;
    }
    TAPBlock blk;
    std::ifstream in{argv[1]};
    while (blk.read(in)) {
        std::cout << blk << '\n';
        if (auto hdr = blk.get_header()) {
            std::cout << *hdr << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Although it makes the code a bit longer, I think I'd start by writing a little "buffer" class, on this general order:

```cpp
class buffer { 
    std::vector<uint8_t> &data;
    std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator pos;
public:
    buffer(std::vector<uint8_t> &data) 
        : data(data)
        , pos(data.cbegin()) 
    {}

    void read(char *dest, size_t len) {
        std::copy_n(pos, dest, len);        
        pos += len;
    }

    void read(uint16_t &dest) {
        dest = *pos++;
        dest |= *pos++ << 8;
    }
};
```

Using this, the `ctor` for TAPHeader comes out something like this:

```cpp
    explicit TAPHeader(std::vector<uint8_t> const &data, TAPHeader &hdr) {
        buffer b(data);
        b.read(&type, sizeof(type));
        b.read(filename, sizeof(filename)-1);
        filename[10] = '\0';
        b.read(data_len);
        b.read(param1);
        b.read(param2);
    }
```

I find that enough cleaner and simpler to justify the code for `buffer`.

- For the `flag` member of TAPBlock, I'd probably do something like this:

```cpp
enum Flag : uint8_t { header = 0, body = 0xff } flag;
```

Then get_header could come out something like this:

```cpp
    std::optional<TAPHeader> get_header() const {
        const int min_header_size = 17;

        if (flag == header && data.size() >= min_header_size) {
            return TAPHeader{data};
        }
        return {};
    }
```

At least to me, this expresses the intent a bit more clearly.

- Right now, you print out the raw checksums (as read, and as computed) and leave it to the reader to verify that they match. Personally, I'd prefer to have the computer do that check (and consider omitting the message entirely if they match, as well as adding ANSI code to print it in bright red if they mismatch).

Comment: I like your buffer idea.  I had written two standalone templated functions, `readu16` and `readu8` but I think this approach is cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

Some comments to consider:

- In `TAPBlock::read`, I wouldn't try to get cute and declare the two variables `lo` and `hi` on the same line. Instead, I would do `const uint8_t lo = in.get();` and then `const uint8_t hi = in.get();` on the next line. (So just pay attention to const correctness).
- Also, `TAPBlock::operator<<` looks a little strange with its if-else. First, did you really mean `if (1 || blk.flag) { ... }`? That is, taking a logical OR with constant 1 seems unnecessary. Here also the else-branch does nothing and is useless. Perhaps you'd like to restructure this as something like `if(!blk.flag) { return out ... }` after which write no explicit else but just do what you need to do.
- If we wanted to, we could maybe write a small helper for the constructor of `TAPHeader` as the two lines that operate on `data_len`, `param1` and `param2` do the same thing (but maybe that will only clutter things, so it's OK). By the way, we could also write `auto it = v.cbegin();` but that's just personal preference, I do see that `v` is passed in as const.
- We could add a precondition (e.g., `assert(data.size() == 17 && "Unexpected input length")`) to `TAPHeader` constructor and not just assume `it` is always dereferenceable. At the same time, why not make a `constexpr` constant for 17 so that it's not so magical as we use it at least twice in the code.
- Arguably, the loop `for (auto count{ len - 2 }; count; --count) { ... }` is not written as readable as it could be. Isn't it clearer to write `for (auto count{0}; count < len - 2; ++count) { ... }`. In fact, I suppose you could also just do a call to something like `std::generate_n` with a lambda that return `in.get()` to populate the data vector but that might be overkill and actually just hurt readability.

Comment: Absolutely right on the `(1 || blk.flag)`  -- that was residue from an earlier experiment.  The current code does not have an `if`.

Comment: @Edward No worries, I figured that was the case.

Answer (score 6):

The parameters to the `TAPHeader` constructor and `TAPBlock::operator<<` could be passed as const references to avoid making copies of the objects being passed.

```cpp
explicit TAPHeader(const std::vector<uint8_t> &v);
// ...
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const TAPBlock &blk);
```

In the `TAPHeader` constructor, you calculate the two byte length values as you read the bytes for it, but in `TAPBlock::read`, you read two bytes into local variables then use those to calculate the length. For consistency you should use the same style for both. `read` can be changed to start:

```cpp
len = in.get();
len |= in.get() << 8;
```

then you wouldn't need the `lo` or `hi` variables.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to factor out something like a templated `get_uint16()` that would work with both the `std::vector` and with a `std::ifstream`.  Seems like I ought to be able to pass an iterator, but it has eluded me so far.

Comment: @Edward I consider that as well, and the closest I got was to use a templated function, with a `std::istream_iterator`. But I stopped because of the difference between how the passed in value would be updated. The iterator would want a reference to the iterator so it could updated, while the istream_iterator could get by without it (but with the reference would need a named variable at the call site).